# retrieving array value on mouseover with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to figure out a way to retrieve and display the value of a div tag that is created  with a 2D array using JavaScript. I figured either onclick or onmouseover would work but neither would in this approach. I would like to avoid creating 49 functions that does the same thing (just displaying the 'cell' the mouse is over).

```
<style type="text/css">
  .float {float: left;}
  .clear {clear:both;}
  div {border: thin solid blue; padding: 2px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grid"></div>
    <div id="bucket" class="float"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var axisY = 7;
var axisZ = 7;

for (var i = 0; i < axisY; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < axisZ; j++) {
    document.getElementById('grid').innerHTML += "<div onmouseout='displayNone()' onmouseover='displayMe(cellId)' id='area" + i + j + "' class='float'>" + i + ":" + j + "</div>";
  }
  document.getElementById('grid').innerHTML += "<br class='clear' />";
}

function displayMe(cellId) {
  // ???
}

function displayNone() {
  document.getElementById('bucket').innerHTML = "";
}
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: by cell id you mean 'area12' ? or 1:2 ? or anything else?

Comment: how do you want to display it?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the cell id by passing this.id into the function.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var axisY = 7;
var axisZ = 7;

for (var i = 0; i < axisY; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < axisZ; j++) {
    document.getElementById('grid').innerHTML += "<div onmouseout='displayNone()' onmouseover='displayMe(this.id)' id='area" + i + j + "' class='float'>" + i + ":" + j + "</div>";
  }
  document.getElementById('grid').innerHTML += "<br class='clear' />";
}

function displayMe(cellId) {
  console.log(cellId);
}

function displayNone() {
  document.getElementById('bucket').innerHTML = "";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Right now you have set up each cell element to call the function `displayMe` whenever the `mouseover` event occurs. When you call that function, you are passing the variable `cellId` as an argument. The problem is when that function is called, `cellId` is not defined. You can see this error pop up in your browser's developer console ("Uncaught ReferenceError: cellId is not defined").

You probably want to pass the cell element's `id` property, which you define dynamically here: `id='area" + i + j + "'`. You can use the `id` property of an element to look up the element (as you have done already), and get the text it contains via `textContent`.

To pass the cell element's `id` property, you need to use the `this` variable, like so: `this.id`. `this` will refer to the element that is triggering the event. So, if you change your `onmouseover` value of your div element to this: `onmouseover='displayMe(this.id)'`, it will pass the appropriate value to your `displayMe` function, allowing you to do something like this:

```
function displayMe(cellId) {
    document.getElementById('bucket').innerHTML = document.getElementById(cellId).textContent;
}
```

With these adjustments, your code will look like this in its entirety:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .float {float: left;}
  .clear {clear:both;}
  div {border: thin solid blue; padding: 2px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grid"></div>
    <div id="bucket" class="float"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var axisY = 7;
var axisZ = 7;

for (var i = 0; i < axisY; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < axisZ; j++) {
    document.getElementById('grid').innerHTML += "<div onmouseout='displayNone()' onmouseover='displayMe(this.id)' id='area" + i + j + "' class='float'>" + i + ":" + j + "</div>";
  }
  document.getElementById('grid').innerHTML += "<br class='clear' />";
}

function displayMe(cellId) {
  document.getElementById('bucket').innerHTML = document.getElementById(cellId).textContent;
}

function displayNone() {
  document.getElementById('bucket').innerHTML = "";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ah, I was unaware of the innerText method. This works with one slight tweak:

    function displayMe(cellId) {
     var cellText = document.getElementById(cellId).innerText;
     document.getElementById('bucket').innerHTML = cellText;
    }

Thanks @ahenninger!

Comment: You're very welcome! Yes, your tweak would do the same thing but a little more readable.

Comment: Wasn't me. If I had enough points, I would vote this up as your solution answers my bigger problem within this script.